# Find out which package I have to install on a Linux system

Tags: bash, command-line, rpm, deb

I made a bash script to install a software package on a Linux system.
There are 4 packages I can use to install the software:

1. x86.deb
2. x86.rpm
3. x86_64.deb
4. x86_64.rpm

I know when to install which package on which Linux server manually, but I would like to find out "automatically" (in my bash script) which one I have to install.

Is there any command to find out?
I already know there is a way to find out the architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) via the "arch" command, but I do not know how to find out which package I need.

Comment: How did you end up in a situation where these files are collected smack dab all in one place? The correct solution would almost certainly be to divide them into separate repositories in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uname -m` or `arch` gives you the architecture (`x86_64` or similar).

You can probably figure out whether your system is based on RPM or DEB (e.g. Ubuntu is DEB-based) by asking both variants which package installed `/bin/ls`:

```
dpkg -S /bin/ls
```

will print

```
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

on a DEB-based system.

```
rpm -q -f /bin/ls
```

will print

```
coreutils-5.97-23.el5_6.4
```

on an RPM-based system (with probably different version numbers).

On the "wrong" system each of these will give an error message instead.

```
if dpkg -S /bin/ls >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  case "$(arch)" in
    x86_64)
      sudo dpkg -i x86_64.deb;;
    i386)
      sudo dpkg -i x86.deb;;
    *)
      echo "Don't know how to handle $(arch)"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
elif rpm -q -f /bin/ls >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  case "$(arch)" in
    x86_64)
      sudo rpm -i x86_64.rpm;;
    i386)
      sudo rpm -i x86.rpm;;
    *)
      echo "Don't know how to handle $(arch)"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
else
  echo "Don't know this package system (neither RPM nor DEB)."
  exit 1
fi
```

Of course, all this only makes sense in case you know what to do then, i.e. if you know which package is to be installed on which package system with which architecture.